# Spielman's proof of graph connectivity

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

I use Spielman's lectures on course **Spectral Graph Theory**

I have few question regarding [Lecture 2. The Laplacian](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/561/lect02-09.pdf), especially *Lemma 2.3.1* (Graph connectivity). Please, help me to make it a little bit clearer.

> *Lemma 2.3.1*. Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph, and let $0=\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \cdots\leq \lambda_n $ be the eigenvalues of its Laplacian matrix. Then, $\lambda_2 >0 $ if and only if $G$ is connected.

*Proof:*
We first show that $\lambda_{2}=0$  if $G$ is disconnected. If $G$ is disconnected, then it can be described as the union of two graphs, $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$. After suitably re-numbering the vertices, we can write

$$L_{G}=\begin{bmatrix}
L_{G_{1}}  & 0\\
0  &  L_{G_{2}}
\end{bmatrix}.$$

So, $L_{G}$ has at least two orthogonal eigenvectors of eigenvalue zero:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}
\mbox{ and } 
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

where we have partitioned the vectors as we did the matrix $L_{G}$.

> What does it mean "orthogonal eigenvectors of eigenvalue zero"? Are those eigenvalues really equal 0? How do we know that these eigenvalues correspond to $\lambda_{2}$? I suspect that all $\lambda$'s are ordered by multiplicity. But how can I prove that every $n$ by $n$ symmetric matrix has $n$ eigenvalues, counted with multiplicity.

On the other hand, assume that $G$ is connected and that $x$ is an eigenvector of $L_{G}$ of eigenvalue $0$. As $L_{G}x=0$, we have

$$x^{T}L_{G}x=\sum_{(u,v)\in E}^{} (x(u)-x(v))^{2} = 0.$$

Thus, for each pair of vertices $(u,v)$ connected by an edge, we have $x(u)=x(v)$.

> Why actually it's true if $u$ and $v$ are connected by an edge, we have $x(u)=x(v)$, it's not obvious for me, even if $x$ is eigenvector, and what happens in the general case?

As every pair of vertices $u$ and $v$  are connected by a path, we may inductively apply this fact to show that $x(u)=x(v)$ for all vertices $u$ and $v$. Thus, $x$ must be a constant vector. We conclude that the eigenspace of eigenvalue $0$ has dimension $1$.

> OK, by now we prove that $\lambda_{1}=0$, but what about $\lambda_{2}$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What does it mean "orthogonal eigenvectors of eigenvalue zero"? Are those eigenvalues really equal 0?

Eigenvector for eigenvalue zero is a vector $\mathbf{a}$ such that $L\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{0}$. In this case
$$\begin{bmatrix}
L_{G_{1}}  & 0\\
0  &  L_{G_{2}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ and }
\begin{bmatrix}
L_{G_{1}}  & 0\\
0  &  L_{G_{2}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$
hence the vectors $\mathbf{a}_1=[1,\dots,1,0,\dots,0]^T$ and $\mathbf{a}_2=[0,\dots,0,1,\dots,1]^T$ are eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalue 0.

They are orthogonal since $\mathbf{a}_1^T\mathbf{a}_2=0$. Since we know that these vectors are orthogonal, they must be linearly independent.

> How do we know that these eigenvalues correspond to $\lambda_2$?

Since the eigenvalues are ordered increasingly and we have two linearly independent eigenvectors, i.e. at least two eigenvalues are zero, we know that $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$.

> I suspect that all $\lambda$'s are ordered by multiplicity. But how can I prove that every n by n symmetric matrix has n eigenvalues, counted with multiplicity.

Eigenvalues are roots of characteristic polynomial, which has degree $n$. So, counting multiplicity, there is $n$ of them. Here we are speaking about algebraic multiplicity, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue#Algebraic_and_geometric_multiplicities).

> Why actually it's true if $u$ and $v$ are connected by an edge, we have $x(u)=x(v)$, it's not obvious for me, even if $x$ is eigenvector, and what happens in the general case?

Since $\sum\limits_{(u,v)\in E}^{} (x(u)-x(v))^{2} = 0$ is a sum of non-negative real numbers, each of them must be zero. So we have $(x(u)-x(v))^{2}=0$ and, consequently, $(x(u)-x(v))=0$, for each $(u,v)\in E$.

> OK, by now we prove that $\lambda_{1}=0$, but what about $\lambda_{2}$?

It was shown in the preceding part of the proof, that (if $G$ is connected) every eigenvector for zero is multiple of $[1,1,\dots,1]^T$. This shows that eigenspace corresponding to zero eigenvalue has dimension 1, i.e., the geometric multiplicity of this eigenvalue is 1.

EDIT: What I wrote here before was unnecessary complicated. Laplacian matrix is symmetric, hence it is diagonalizable. Thus algebraic and geometric multiplicity are the same.

<s>However, we need to show that algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda_1=0$ is 1. Suppose this would be not true. It would imply that there exists a vector $\mathbf a$  such that $L \mathbf a = [1,1,\dots,1]^T$. This would imply that vector $[1,1,\dots,1]^T$ belongs to the [column space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_space) of the matrix $L$. But directly from the definition of of [Laplacian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) we can see that this vector is orthogonal to each column of $L$. (At least for non-weighted graphs - I did not think about the weighted case.)</s>

<s>I agree with you that this last argument seems to be missing in the pdf-file you linked. (And probably different explanations are possible.)</s>

---

Just a few words of explanation. (But it is better to read it with more details at wiki or in some linear algebra textbook.)

If $\mathbf{a}$ is an eigenvector of a matrix $A$, it means that $(A-\lambda I)\mathbf a=\mathbf 0$. If algebraic multiplicity (=the multiplicity of $\lambda$ as a root of characteristic polynomial) is greater than the geometric multiplicity (=dimension of the corresponding eigenspace), it implies that there is an eigenvector $\mathbf a$  and a [generalized eigenvector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) $\mathbf b$ such that $(A-\lambda I)\mathbf b=\mathbf a$ .

<s>This was the property which we used in the last paragraph.</s>

Geometric multiplicity is precisely the number of Jordan blocks in the [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).

---

It might be worth mentioning, that in the book Bapat: Graphs and Matrices, Universitext, Springer 2010, the Laplacian matrix is defined as follows.
The author first defines
the (vertex-edge) *incidence matrix* of G denoted by $Q(G)$, which is the $n\times m$ matrix with entries $0$ if the given vertex and edge are incident, $1$  if the edge starts in this vertex and $-1$ if it ends there. It is relatively easy to show that rank of $Q(G)$ is $n-k$, where $k$ is the number of connected components of this graph, see [p.11-12](http://books.google.com/books?id=w5oXUgN5xw0C&pg=PA11) of this book.

Then the Laplacian matrix can be obtained as $L(G)=Q(G)Q(G)^T$, see [p.45](http://books.google.com/books?id=w5oXUgN5xw0C&pg=PA45)

Using this fact we get $\operatorname{rank}(L)=\operatorname{rank}(QQ^T)=\operatorname{rank}(Q)$, see [Lemma 4.3, p.46](http://books.google.com/books?id=w5oXUgN5xw0C&pg=PA11).

The fact that matrix $Q$ and its [Gram matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) $QQ^T$ have the same rank is mentioned in the same book on [p.10](http://books.google.com/books?id=w5oXUgN5xw0C&pg=PA10)
as an exercise:

> Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix. Show that $A$ and $A^TA$ have the same null space. Hence
>   conclude that $\operatorname{rank} A = \operatorname{rank}A^TA$.

I.e., it was shown that $n-\operatorname{rank}(G)$ is the number of connected components.
Since $L(G)$ is symmetric, it is diagonalizable, and thus this is the same as the number of non-zero eigenvalues.

Again, I do not know whether something similar can be done in the weighted case.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation. But I still cannot understand, in second part of the proof, we proved just if $G$ is connected than $\lambda_{1}=0$, but there is nothing about $\lambda_{2} \neq 0$. $\lambda_{1}=0$ doesn't conclude that $\lambda_{2} \neq 0$.

Comment: Again - I tried to explain this above: It was shown that eigenspace corresponding to 0 consist only of constant vectors, i.e. multiples of [1,1,...,1]^T. This means this eigenspace is one-dimensional and the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ is $1$. (In this case, algebraic and geometric multiplicity is the same.) This is precisely the same thing as to say that $\lambda_2\ne0$.